# Cloudinary responsive image with auto height instead of auto width

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, responsive-design, image-resizing, cloudinary

So I read the recent Cloudinary blog post about responsive image tags. In particular, I use this line right now (for Ruby on Rails 2.1):

`cl_image_tag("example.jpg", :width => :auto, :responsive_placeholder => "blank")` and then `<script type="text/javascript">$.cloudinary.responsive()</script>`

This works as expected; Cloudinary responsively resizes the image to scale and take up as much **width** as allowed.

However, I want to responsively resize the image to take as much **height** as allowed. What is the best way to do this, as I don't think it is built into `$.cloudinary.responsive()`?

Thank you for your time!

Links I read:
http://cloudinary.com/blog/how_to_automatically_create_images_for_responsive_design
https://github.com/cloudinary/cloudinary_js/blob/master/js/jquery.cloudinary.js#L675

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently the `$.cloudinary.responsive()` method is supported for automatic width only. Cloudinary is working on extending the responsive support for automatic height too.